# How to check value pasted to clipboard with AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm an AppleScript noob, and I really want to do something nice with it. How can I make an AppleScript that runs at all times checking for clipboard changes? What I want to do is check the clipboard, see if it's a certain value, and make a web request with that clipboard value.

This is what I currently have, it just gets the value that's in the current clipboard

```
get the clipboard
set the clipboard to "my text"
```

Any help will be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

AppleScript does not have a way to “wait for the clipboard to change”, so you will have to “poll” the clipboard at regular intervals.

## `repeat` loop with a pause

```
set oldvalue to missing value
repeat
    set newValue to the clipboard
    if oldvalue is not equal to newValue then
        try

            if newValue starts with "http://" then
                tell application "Safari" to make new document with properties {URL:newValue}
            end if

        end try
        set oldvalue to newValue
    end if

    delay 5

end repeat
```

<sup>Some might use `do shell script "sleep 5"` instead of `delay 5`; I have never had a problem with `delay`, but I have never use it in a long-running program like this one.</sup>

Depending on the launcher used to run this program such a script might “tie up” the application and prevent it from launching other programs (some launchers can only run one AppleScript program at a time).

## “Stay Open” application with `idle` handler

A better alternative is to save your program as a “Stay Open” application (in the Save As… dialog) and use an [`idle` handler](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW7) for the periodic work.

```
property oldvalue : missing value

on idle
    local newValue
    set newValue to the clipboard
    if oldvalue is not equal to newValue then
        try

            if newValue starts with "http://" then
                tell application "Safari" to make new document with properties {URL:newValue}
            end if

        end try
        set oldvalue to newValue
    end if

    return 5 -- run the idle handler again in 5 seconds

end idle
```